# Show Thousands Separator within input field only

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, keyup

I have added a thousand separator by Javascript keyup to an input field within a standard form:

Form

```
  <form>
   <div class="row mt20">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      </div>
      <div>
         <input id="cal2_txtLoan" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text form-control investment-class-form"  type="text" placeholder="วงเงินกู้(บาท)">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row mt20">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
         <input id="cal2_txtTenor" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text form-control investment-class-form" type="number" placeholder="ระยะเวลากู้ 1-30 ปี">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row mt20">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
         <input id="cal2_txtInterestRate" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text form-control investment-class-form" type="number" placeholder="ดอกเบี้ย(%)">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row mt20">
      <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-9 col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-9">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
               <button type="button" id="cal2_btnCalculate" class="button investment-button">คำนวณ</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row mt20">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <label class="investment-list">สรุปยอดผ่อนต่อเดือน (บาท)</label> <input id="cal2_txtInstallment" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text form-control investment-class-form" disabled="disabled" type="text"> <span class="investment-list" style="color:red;">* ผลลัพธ์จากการคำนวณ เป็นเพียงผลการคำนวณเบื้องต้นเท่านั้น โปรดติดต่อธนาคารเพื่อคำนวณยอดที่ถูกต้องอีกครั้งหนึ่ง</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Javascript Event Keyup

```
 <script>
    var cal2_txtLoan = document.getElementById('cal2_txtLoan');
    
    cal2_txtLoan.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      var val = this.value;
      val = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
      
      if(val != "") {
        valArr = val.split('.');
        valArr[0] = (parseInt(valArr[0],10)).toLocaleString();
        val = valArr.join('.');
      }
      
      this.value = val;
    });
    
    </script>
```

It works correctly, but now my form cannot submit because of the comma "," in the value

How can I display my decimal separator in the input field, but only submit the value.

Rest of my calculation for reference:

```
    <script>
function CalculatePMT(pv, rate, years) {
                return Math.round(pv * (rate / 100 / 12) / (1 - 1 / Math.pow ((1 + rate / 100 / 12) , ( years * 12))));
    
            }
           
            /************** CALCULATE LOAN *************/
            $("#cal2_btnCalculate").click(Calculate2);
    
            function Calculate2(event) {
                var years = $("#cal2_txtTenor").val();
                var rate = $("#cal2_txtInterestRate").val();
                var pv = $("#cal2_txtLoan").val();
                if (CheckForDigit(years) && CheckForDigit(rate) && CheckForDigit(pv)) {
                    var ir = (rate / 100) * 100; // For LH, add 1 more
                    var installment = CalculatePMT(pv, ir, years);
                    $("#cal2_txtInstallment").val(FormatNumberToString(installment));
                    $("#cal2_txtMinimumIncome").val(FormatNumberToString(installment ));
                } else
                    alert("ไม่สามารถคำนวนวงเงินสินเชื่อเพื่อการซื้อบ้านได้");
            }
            /*****************************************/
          
        });
       
        </script
```

Comment: maybe parseInt https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#using_parseint

ie: ParseInt(15.23) = 15 

but if youre allowing a user to submit decimals you should probably not ignore the decimal values.

Comment: Off topic: `this.value = val` will reposition the cursor/user input to the end of the input box. If the user does anything other than just typing in numbers, this will annoy them very quickly - this is a terrible UX.

Comment: The title of the question is incorrect - it's not the "decimal separator" but the "thousands separator" - ie the `,` in `1,000`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onsubmit="return deleteThousandSeparator(event)">
  ...
</form>


function deleteThousandSeparator(){
  const cal2_txtLoan = document.getElementById('cal2_txtLoan');
  cal2_txtLoan.value = cal2_txtLoan.value.replace('.','')
}
```

Comment: The title of the question is incorrect - it's not the "decimal separator" but the "thousands separator" - ie the `,` in `1,000`

Comment: @freedomn-m It depends of the country, in Spain the thousands separator is a dot and the decimal separator a comma.

Comment: @ManuelMB correct, but equally blindly changing `1.23` to `123` will be a **massive** issue if you don't check for the locale first!   My comment was based on OPs statement: *my form cannot submit because of the comma "," in the value*.  So you've raised a valid, larger issue.

Comment: This seems like the best method- but I couldn't get it to work. I have aded the full form for context, because perhaps it is because i am using a button type = "button" and not submit. @ManualMB

Comment: @ACE-CM Place the code before where you submit the form